# SwitchListTile not turning on in a Dialog

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a workable switchlist in a Dialog. The Switch with icon, title shows but is not turning on.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(AntDesign.sound),
                label: Text('Sound Options'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        child: SimpleDialog(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SimpleDialogOption(
                              child: SwitchListTile(
                                  title: Text('Mute'),
                                  secondary: Icon(AntDesign.sound),
                                  value: _mute,
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _mute = value;
                                    });
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ));
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

setState rebuilds your build method and change the _mute value, but the SimpleDialog is open in another context, so that dialog is not rebuild. You should make a new StatefulWidget with the AlertDialog and setState when changing the value there

```
class Class1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Class1State createState() => _Class1State();
}

class _Class1State extends State<Class1> {
  bool _mute = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(AntDesign.sound),
                label: Text('Sound Options'),
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => MyDialog(_mute)
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  bool mute;

  MyDialog(this.mute);

  @override
  _MyDialogState createState() => _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      children: <Widget>[
        SimpleDialogOption(
          child: SwitchListTile(
            title: Text('Mute'),
            secondary: Icon(AntDesign.sound), 
            value: widget.mute,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                widget.mute = value;
              });
            }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Another few tips, use builder instead of child with showDialog, child is deprecated, don't wrap the whole SimpleDialog in a setState, you should just wrap the value you're going to change, wrapping the dialog won't make it rebuild with the new value.

From the documentation

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of
>   this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface
>   in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for
>   this State object.

the setState you use rebuilds the subtree of your whole Scaffold Stateful Widget, but the Dialog is open in another tree, it's not part of that subtree, If you use Android Studio there is a flutter inspector (and I believe Visual Studio has it too), you can see there that the dialog and your StatefulWidget come from Material App (the dialog is not part of the subtree so it won't rebuild)